# Copying emojis in text from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, unicode, emoji, collation

I am copying data from MySQL to SQL Server using a linked server.

```
SELECT comment FROM openquery(my_linked_server, 'SELECT comment FROM search_data');
```

The text in the MySQL table column is `xxx  xxx` . By time I receive it in SQL Server it is `xxx ðŸ¤˜ xxx`. The MySQL table is `utf8mb4`, and I have set up the ODBC config for the linked server to use this. I am using MySQL ODBC 5.3.13

Any advice would be appreciated. the SQL Server version is 2016, I have seen examples to put do

```
select N''
```

etc, but don't know how to apply this to the above query.

ðŸ¤˜ seems to be 4 characters

```
ð = u00f0 , dec = 240
Ÿ = u0178 , dec = 276
¤ = u00a4 , dec = 164
˜ = u02dc , dec =  732
```

= ud83e, dec = 55358

funny enough this doesnt even work

```
select nchar(unicode(N'')),unicode(N'')
```

returning � symbol

Comment: `ðŸ¤` is an example of Mojibake; I call `�` a black diamond.  I discuss the causes of both in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a solution and posting so others dont spend the day doing the same

```
select ab_test.dbo.GetEmojisInString('ðŸ‘ŒðŸ’–ðŸ¤·â€â™‚ï¸ðŸ˜ŽðŸ±â€ðŸ’»ðŸ˜‰â¤ðŸ±â€ðŸ‘¤ðŸ¤žðŸ¤£ðŸ‘ðŸ’•âœŒðŸ±â€ðŸðŸ’‹ðŸŽ‚ðŸŽ‰ðŸ¤¦â€â™‚ï¸ðŸ˜ŠðŸŒ¹ðŸ‘ðŸ±â€ðŸ‰ðŸŽ¶ðŸ˜ðŸ¤¦â€â™€ï¸ðŸ˜ðŸ™ŒðŸ±â€ðŸš€ðŸ˜œðŸ˜˜ðŸ±â€ðŸ‘“ðŸ˜¢ðŸ˜’ðŸ¤³ðŸ˜‚')
```

will return

‍♂️‍❤‍✌‍‍♂️‍‍♀️‍‍

there are 5 functions below, probrably not perfect and maybe shorter / better ways but this functions. if any bugs let me know.

NOTE : i had to split over two databases as for this to work the collation needs to have _CS, and the bi_library database below in my solution i could not change this as database was locked so for now just created a ab_test db.

```
USE [bi_library]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDecimalFromOtherBase]
(  @p_in_value   varchar(100),
   @p_from_base  int -- ie 16 for hex, 8 for octal, 2 for bin
) returns int
as
begin
    declare @l_in_value varchar(100) = reverse(@p_in_value) -- spin backwards as maths works in easier this way
    declare @l_from_base varchar(100) = @p_from_base--@p_from_base --= @p_in_value
    declare @l_pos int = 1
    declare @l_char char(1)
    declare @l_val int = 0
    declare @l_total int = 0

    while @l_pos<= len(@l_in_value)
    begin
       set @l_char = substring(@l_in_value,@l_pos,1)

       if isnumeric(@l_char)=0
       begin
          set @l_val = ascii(@l_char)-55 -- convert A to 10, F to 15 etc
       end 
       else
       begin
          set @l_val = @l_char
       end

       set @l_total = @l_total + (power(@l_from_base,@l_pos-1)*@l_val)
       set @l_pos=@l_pos+1
    end
    return @l_total
end
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOtherBaseFromDecimal]
(  @p_in_value   int,
   @p_to_base  int -- ie 16 for hex, 8 for octal, 2 for bin
) returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    -- convert decimal to other base
    declare @l_dec int = @p_in_value
    declare @l_ret_str varchar(100) = ''
    declare @l_rem int = 0
    declare @l_rem_char char(1) = '?'
    while @l_dec > 0
    begin
          set @l_rem = @l_dec % @p_to_base
          if @l_rem >= 10
          begin
             set @l_rem_char = char(55+@l_rem)
          end
          else
          begin
             set @l_rem_char = cast(@l_rem as varchar)
          end

          set @l_ret_str = @l_ret_str + @l_rem_char
          set @l_dec = @l_dec / @p_to_base
    end
    return reverse(@l_ret_str)
end
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBaseFromOtherBase]
(  @p_in_value varchar(100),
   @p_in_base  bigint, -- ie 16 for hex, 8 for octal, 2 for bin
   @p_to_base  bigint -- ie 16 for hex, 8 for octal, 2 for bin
) returns varchar(100)
as
begin
   return bi_library.dbo.GetOtherBaseFromDecimal(bi_library.dbo.GetDecimalFromOtherBase(@p_in_value,@p_in_base),@p_to_base)
end
GO

USE [ab_test]
GO



ALTER function [dbo].[GetEmojisInString] (@p_in_string nvarchar(max)) returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @l_string varchar(1000) = @p_in_string --'âœŒðŸ˜ðŸ’‹ðŸ¤·â€â™‚ï¸ðŸ¤³ðŸ±â€ðŸ‘“ðŸ±â€ðŸš€ðŸ±â€ðŸ‰ðŸ˜ŠðŸ’•ðŸ¤žðŸ˜‰ðŸ‘ŒðŸ¤¦â€â™€ï¸ðŸ±â€ðŸðŸ’–ðŸ˜’ðŸ˜˜ðŸ˜ðŸ‘ðŸ¤¦â€â™‚ï¸ðŸ‘ðŸ±â€ðŸ‘¤ðŸ±â€ðŸ’»ðŸ™ŒðŸŽ‚ðŸ˜ŽðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜¢ðŸ˜œðŸŽ¶ðŸŒ¹ðŸŽ‰ðŸ¤£â¤ðŸ¤·â€â™€ï¸'
    declare @l_pos    int = 1
    declare @l_char   varchar(1)
    declare @l_cont_extended_ascii int = 0
    declare @l_byte1_hex varchar(2)
    declare @l_byte2_hex varchar(2)
    declare @l_byte3_hex varchar(2)
    declare @l_byte4_hex varchar(2)
    declare @l_hex_char  varchar(2)
    declare @l_str       nvarchar(max) = ''
    declare @l_dec_value_found int

    while   @l_pos  <= len(@l_string)
    begin
       set @l_char = substring(@l_string,@l_pos,1)
       --print(ascii(@l_char))
       if ascii(@l_char)>=128 
       begin
          set @l_cont_extended_ascii = @l_cont_extended_ascii+1
          --print(@l_char)
          set @l_hex_char = bi_library.dbo.GetOtherBaseFromDecimal(ascii(@l_char),16)
          if  @l_cont_extended_ascii = 1 
          begin 
             set @l_byte1_hex = @l_hex_char 
             --print('set byte 1')
          end
          else if @l_cont_extended_ascii = 2 
          begin 
             --print('set byte 2')
             set @l_byte2_hex = @l_hex_char
             set @l_dec_value_found = bi_library.dbo.GetDecimalFromOtherBase(
                       reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte1_hex,16,2)),1,6))+
                       reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte2_hex,16,2)),1,6))
                                          ,2)
              if @l_dec_value_found between 128/*U+0080*/ and 2047/*U+07FF  */
              begin
                 --print('2 byte emoji found')
                 set @l_str = @l_str+coalesce(nchar(@l_dec_value_found),'?')
                 set @l_cont_extended_ascii = 0
              end

          end
          else if @l_cont_extended_ascii = 3 
          begin 
              --print('set byte 3')
              set @l_byte3_hex = @l_hex_char 
              set @l_dec_value_found = bi_library.dbo.GetDecimalFromOtherBase(
                       reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte1_hex,16,2)),1,4))+
                       reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte2_hex,16,2)),1,6))+
                       reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte3_hex,16,2)),1,6))
                                          ,2)
              if @l_dec_value_found between 2048/*U+0800*/ and 65535/*U+FFFF*/
              begin
                 --print('3 byte emoji found')
                 set @l_str = @l_str+coalesce(nchar(@l_dec_value_found),'?')
                 set @l_cont_extended_ascii = 0
              end
               --print(@l_str)
          end
          else if @l_cont_extended_ascii = 4 begin set @l_byte4_hex = @l_hex_char

                   set @l_dec_value_found = bi_library.dbo.GetDecimalFromOtherBase(
                                                   reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte1_hex,16,2)),1,3))+
                                                   reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte2_hex,16,2)),1,6))+
                                                   reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte3_hex,16,2)),1,6))+
                                                   reverse(substring(reverse(bi_library.dbo.GetBaseFromOtherBase(@l_byte4_hex,16,2)),1,6))
                                                                      ,2)
                   if @l_dec_value_found between 65536/*U+10000*/ and 1114111/*U+10FFFF*/
                   begin
                      --print('4 byte emoji found')
                      set @l_str = @l_str+coalesce(nchar(@l_dec_value_found),'?')
                      set @l_cont_extended_ascii = 0
                   end
                   else
                   begin
                      --print('out of range byte emoji found')
                      set @l_str = @l_str+@l_char
                   end
                    --print(@l_str)
             --end


             set @l_cont_extended_ascii = 0  
          end
       end
       else
       begin
          --print('snapping')
          set @l_str = @l_str+@l_char
          set @l_cont_extended_ascii = 0
           --print(@l_str)
       end


       set @l_pos = @l_pos+1
    end
    --print(@l_str)
    return @l_str
end

CREATE function [dbo].[HasEmojisInString] (@p_in_string nvarchar(max)) returns int
as
begin
    declare @l_string_emojified varchar(1000)
    set @l_string_emojified = dbo.GetEmojisInString(@p_in_string) 
    if @l_string_emojified <> @p_in_string
    begin
       return 1
    end
    return 0
end
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode codepoint of the character  is [U+1F918](https://emojipedia.org/sign-of-the-horns/), which means it is outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)) (BMP) of Unicode, which covers codepoints up to U+FFFF.

To process Unicode characters outside the BMP, you need to apply [collations supporting Supplementary Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support), named as *`_SC`:

> SQL Server 2012 (11.x) introduced a new family of supplementary character (_SC) collations that can be used with the nchar, nvarchar, and sql_variant data types to represent the full Unicode character range (000000–10FFFF)

Compare the results of this SQL statement

```
select 
    nchar(unicode(N'' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC)) as EmojiSC, 
    unicode(N'' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC) as EmojiSCUnicode, 
    cast(N'' as varbinary) as EmojiBinary, 
    cast(nchar(unicode(N'')) as varbinary) as EmojiConvBinary,
    unicode(N'') as EmojiUnicode
```

as run against a database using `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

```
EmojiSC EmojiSCUnicode  EmojiBinary EmojiConvBinary EmojiUnicode
NULL    129304          0x3ED818DD  0x3ED8          55358
```

versus a database set to `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC`

```
EmojiSC EmojiSCUnicode  EmojiBinary EmojiConvBinary EmojiUnicode
      129304          0x3ED818DD  0x3ED818DD      129304
```

**Why do you see "`ðŸ¤˜`"?**

The UTF-8 encoding of U+1F918 is [0xF0 0x9F 0xA4 0x98](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f918/index.htm), and the characters are the result of interpreting these codes as [ANSI characters](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php).

**Why do you see "�"?**

The character � is the Unicode [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) and is

> used to replace an unknown, unrecognized or unrepresentable character

and that's because U+D83E is [not a valid Unicode codepoint](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d83e/index.htm), but the first word of the codepoint encoded as UTF-16 (`0xD83E 0xDD18`).

**Check what is stored, not what is displayed**

Displaying Unicode data can be tricky, and the most efficient way to find out what's going on under the hood is to look at the bytes. In TSQL, use `cast(... as varbinary)` to analyze where Unicode data manipulation goes wrong.

Comment: my collation has _SC on the end, and still comes out as those 4 bytes, do you know the mathematical way to put the UTF-8 encoding back together to make the emoji