# SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL (Chinese display error)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration, data-migration

## SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL (Chinese display error)

**I am using SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL to migrate from Mysql to SQL Server**

**After the migration data is completed Chinese display ?? Error display!**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3H7k.png]

**迁移工具**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELwFc.png]

Comment: I stayed on this issue for two days, Hope to get help, thanks!

Comment: try to find out what binary data is stored, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58558460/21336 . after that, maybe it is just a font/display problem.

Comment: thank you
Chinese display ? I have solved the problem
It is normal for these data to be displayed in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our data is available in four languages 
zh_TW
zh_CN
pt_PT
en

I finally solved the problem completely

When I link SQL server data, I set charset = utf8, but there are still individual displays in Chinese Simplified "?"

At last, we set the field type to nvarchar (max). At first, I knew that modifying the field type could solve the problem, but we were migrating data and could not modify the field type. Using symfony schema update to generate SQL statements also did not support nvarchar (max). At last, we modified the source code of generating SQL statements. Using text type, we could compile nvarchar (max)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbXMT.png)